# Is there a way to combine two seperate `Searchkick::Results` objects in to one

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

Is there a way to combine two seperate `Searchkick::Results` object in to one.

E.g

```
user = User.search("abc", where: { <condition 1 > })
blog = Blog.search("abc", where: { <condition 2 > })
```

combined  both results to a one Searchkick::Results object so that I can use pagination , relevance search etc.. as a one unit.

I had a look at [Multi Search](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick), but that seems to be not doing what I want

PS: I've opened a ticket in [searchkick repo asking the same](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/1113)

Comment: It's different results set. I wonder what is your use case.

Comment: hey @aclokay, this is for a search page, where different tabs has different scopes. E.g users, blogs etc and you get to search each scope. First tab is called `All` and that expect to return search results across all the scopes

Answer (score 1):

`user = User.search("abc", where: { <condition 1 > })`

`blog = Blog.search("abc", where: { <condition 2 > })`

Convert two objects into an array and merge array using `concat` method.

**`user_blog = user.to_a.concat(blog.to_a)`**

Answer (score 1):

You can search across multiple indices with:

```
where = {
  _or: [
    {_type: "user", somefield: "value1"},
    {_type: "blog", otherfield: "value2"}
  ]
}
Searchkick.search "abc", index_name: [User, Blog], where: where
```

[Source](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#multiple-indices)